# Anime Western with a young boy with a gun?

Tags: wild-arms

I remember watching an anime that was very gun-centric, and had a young boy character who had a gun.  I think I got the sample DVD as some sort of tie-in, maybe with a video game magazine.  I only watched the sample couple of episodes on the DVD and remember liking it, but don't remember anything else about it.  I would have seen this at some point between 1998-2000.  I think it was a TV series which also had a video game tie-in, which is why I got it with a video game magazine.  I also think I remember a Western setting.  Does this ring a bell with anybody else?

Comment: Gunslinger girl (there are characters that look like boys), Texhnolyze, Grenadier, Madlax, Toshokan Sensou, Noir, Katekyo Hitman Reborn!, and City Hunter all come to mind. Can you give any specifics, such as setting, cast, when you saw it, what types of guns? If it was a TV show or game?

Comment: I don't think there are enough details to identify this. The only thing fairly specific is the (possible) gaming magazine, but if you don't remember which magazine it's just a shot in the dark.

Comment: It was a TV show but had some sort of game tie-in.

Comment: Close vote retracted as this was solved. Apparently the additional info was enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image] [image]

The only other thing I can think of is [Wild Arms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wild_Arms:_Twilight_Venom). It's from circa 1999 and has a kid with a gun in a western setting, but I've never seen the show or played the video game series before, so I've no idea how gun centric it really is.